# Show clock on all displays in lock screen

Tags: 22.04, lock-screen

I have 2 or 3 displays (it depends)

Normally on lock screen i see clock and other things only on the main display. And only a blured wallpaper on other displays.

Is there a way to make it show clock on every monitor?